# performClick() doesn't activate selector

Tags: android, button, radio-button, css-selectors

I created a layout with a radiogroup cotaining two buttons. Then i got a drawable selector.

I applied the selector with `android:background` and with`android:button` to remove the little circles.

In the onCreate method i press one button via `button.performClick()` but the layout of the button doesn't change. Even if i call `button.setChecked(true)` it won't change. 
Actually it works when the fragment is first created. But if i press the second button, load another fragment and come back with the backbutton, the second button is still pressed.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View f = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_season, container,
            false);

    final RadioButton bt = (RadioButton) f.findViewById(R.id.bu_season_tabelle);
    final RadioButton bs = (RadioButton) f.findViewById(R.id.bu_season_spielplan);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            setTabelle(f);
            v.setClickable(false);
            bs.setClickable(true);
        }
    });

    bs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            setSpielplan(f);
            v.setClickable(false);
            bt.setClickable(true);
        }
    });

    bt.performClick();

    return f;
}
```

Would be nice if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Instead of calling `button.performClick()` in `onCreateView()` i have to call it in `onStart()`